# How to save one of the values of a column eliminated by groupBy in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is a sample of the dataFrame I have:

```
+----+------+-------+-----+
| id | pool | start | end |
+----+------+-------+-----+
|   1|   cat|    100|  105|
|   2|   cat|    104|  110|
|   3|   cat|    130|  135|
|   4|   dog|    100|  110|
|   5|   dog|    101|  103|
|   6|   rat|    150|  151|
|   7|   rat|    180|  187|
|   8|   rat|    183|  184|
|   9|   cat|    143|  150|
|  10|   dog|    107|  120|
| ...|   ...|    ...|  ...|
+----+------+-------+-----+
```

And I want to group by the pool while preserving the min and max values seen in the start and end for each pool. Great, I run

```
sourceDataframe.groupBy("pool").agg(min("start"), max("end"))
```

which gives me:

```
+------+-----------+---------+
| pool | min(start)| max(end)|
+------+-----------+---------+
|   cat|        100|      150|
|   dog|        100|      120|
|   rat|        150|      187|
|   ...|        ...|      ...|
+------+-----------+---------+
```

But I want one more thing, which is any id belonging to each pool. If possible, preferably the one with the maximum end (or any other arbitrary requirement I suppose). And if possible, without doing another join after the fact.

Example of success:

```
// If two have the same maximum end, it should just pick an arbitrary one
+------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| pool | min(start)| max(end)| idOfMaxEnd|
+------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|   cat|        100|      150|          9|
|   dog|        100|      120|         10|
|   rat|        150|      187|          7|
|   ...|        ...|      ...|        ...|
+------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Thanks for your time and effort!

Edit: Okay so doing the following almost gives me what I want:

```
sourceDataframe.groupBy("pool").agg(min("start"), max("end"), first("id"))
```

It saves the first ID of each group that it comes across. I would like to save the ID with the maximum end per group, if possible. I know I could solve this by sorting the DataFrame but that would require too much time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function with 2 different windows although I am not sure that it will be more efficient than using `join` (you mentioned that you want to avoid it):

```
val df: DataFrame = Seq(
  (1, "cat", 100, 1335),
  (3, "cat", 130, 135),
  (7, "rat", 180, 187),
  (8, "rat", 183, 184),
).toDF("id", "pool", "start", "end")

val windowSpecEnd  = Window.partitionBy("pool").orderBy(col("end").desc)
val windowSpecStart  = Window.partitionBy("pool").orderBy(col("start"))

val aggDf = df
  .withColumn("min_start", functions.first("start").over(windowSpecStart))
  .withColumn("max_end", functions.first("end").over(windowSpecEnd))
  .withColumn("idOfMaxEnd", functions.first("id").over(windowSpecEnd))
  .select("pool", "min_start", "max_end", "idOfMaxEnd")
  .distinct
aggDf.show

// output:
+----+---------+-------+----------+
|pool|min_start|max_end|idOfMaxEnd|
+----+---------+-------+----------+
| rat|      180|    187|         7|
| cat|      100|   1335|         1|
+----+---------+-------+----------+
```